# Azure webapp IP access restriction is not working with Azure front door

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have an Azure Web App configured such that it can be only accessed from the internal network. The requests would come through an Azure Front door. When Front door redirects the request to the Web App the originating IP is replaced, resulting in that the requests originating from the internal company network to fail. I also tried to edit the white-list rule to include the X-Forwarded-For, but it's not working.

Btw, Have I correctly configured the rule that if 'XXX' is the IP block of my internal company network?

[image: Allow request from the IP block XXX]

Comment: With Front Door, the requests are not redirected. Front Door makes the request to your back-end. The request does not come from the client.

Comment: Does the front door forwards the originating IP in the X-Forwarded-For header? If so, can I use that to restrict the app only to the internal network? If the originating IP is XXX and the IP of the front door is YYY, how should my ip whitelist rule should look like?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it sounds like you currently have your web app configured to only allow access to on your VNet or from a specific internal network.  You'd like to add Front Door to be a front end to your web app, but you're having trouble getting Front Door to work correctly.  Specifically you'd like to still be able to access the web app through Front Door from a resource that is on your internal network.

Your solution is going to be to whitelist Front Door's access to the web app itself.   You can do this by going to the web app's Networking blade and clicking on "Access Restriction"

[image]

Then "Add" a new access restriction rule.  You can use a service tag to specify the possible IP addresses that Front Door will use according to [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/origin-security?tabs=app-service-functions&pivots=front-door-standard-premium#ip-address-filtering).  On source settings select "Service Tag" and select a service tag of "AzureFrontDoor.Backend".

[image]

Make sure you add a "name" and "priority" to the access rule and select "Allow".  After you add the rule Front Door should be able to access your web app.  I don't believe you'll need to add anything related to the X-Forwarded-For header or any of the other rule settings.  If you are using a Network Security Group to further restrict access on your web app you'll need to add the same rule there too.

You'll need to make sure your Front Door origin is pointing correctly to your web app.

This should allow resources on your internal network to also be able to access your web app via Front Door.  If there are other errors or issues you may have to whitelist those resources' access to Front Door.  Let us know if you get any new errors or if this solution works for you.

Comment: Hi Narthring, thanks for the detailed solution you have provided. I have tried it, even though now the web app can be accessed from the internal network, it is also possible to access it from outside.

Comment: The web app needs to be accessible only from the internal network and but the front door to be accessible from public network as it also handles requests for public facing web apps.

Comment: If you only want the web app to be accessible from the internal network then Front Door isn't a good solution for you.  What are you trying to achieve by using Front Door?  Maybe caching and load balancing multiple web apps?

Comment: Actually you may be able to configure a WAF rule to restrict all traffic to your Front Door except your "internal" network traffic:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction  It'll depend on being able to whitelist your "external" IP, the one that the internal network is using to connect to Front Door, and that traffic will go out across the public internet.  If you want a true "internal" solution then the VNET/WebApp may be the better way to go.